# 15 days vacations nature oriented in Quebec

Tags: canada, nature-and-wildlife, quebec

I am looking to make a 15 days vacations in Canada. I live in Paris so I though that the cheapest option would be to land in Montreal. I am looking to do some hiking and to watch beautiful landscapes. I will we there in August. We will be able to rent a car. Which parks to do you recommend?

Please tell me if it is a major mistake to land in Montreal.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Unfortunately your question is asking for an opinion of which there may be many depending on how far away from Montreal you are willing to go.  As it stands your question is likely to be put on hold.  Please review the [Help Center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) regarding questions for this site.

Comment: @Karlson Thank you for your feedback. I will ask this open question on another forum and come back here for more specific questions.

Comment: when you want to visit a country you cam start by looking at the tourism board: http://www.bonjourquebec.com/ regarding where to land I would recommend you to look at flight deals. quebec city is also a possibility. air transat has direct flights from many cities in France.